# VBA Excel how to write Excel formula in the textbox

Tags: excel, vba

How can I put the Excel formula into the textbox?

I tried sth like this:

```
 Sub CivBox()
  With ActiveSheet
   .Shapes("Civils 3").Copy
   [C26].Activate
   .Paste
   .Shapes(.Shapes.Count).Name = "Civils 4"
   .Shapes("Civils 4").TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "=D51"
 End With
End Sub
```

But the only the string is returned

[image]

Is it possible to put the Excel formula into the textBox or shall I prepare it in some cell first, and next link this cell into this textbox as a range?

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using a Shape you could use this

```
Sub x()

ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=A1"

End Sub
```

For a textbox you can use

```
ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Formula = "=A1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this indirectly. You can't put it IN the box, but you can select the textbox (not the contents of the textbox), go to the formula bar, and reference a cell.

Edit: This might help: https://www.solveyourtech.com/how-to-display-a-formula-result-in-a-text-box-in-excel-2010/