# VBA Excel Changing the features of textbox with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have managed with input the textbox to the formula, as per the following query, which I raised a while ago...

[VBA Excel how to write Excel formula in the textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973884/vba-excel-how-to-write-excel-formula-in-the-textbox)

and everything is fine, but I have got problems with input the proper font features into this textbox.

Basically I have two separate sets of code, which I would love to combine into the one

```
Sub Duct1()
   Set myDocument = ActiveSheet
   With myDocument.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 300, 140, 180, 30)
    .name = "Duct1"
      With .TextFrame
     .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        With .Characters
        .Text = "1W-20mm/90' upturn"
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Font.Size = 16
        .Font.Bold = True
     End With
     End With
     .Rotation = 25
     .Fill.Visible = False
     .Line.Visible = False
   End With
 End Sub

  Sub Duct1Desc()
  ActiveSheet.Shapes("Duct1").OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=AB1"
  End Sub
```

For the second code I tried also:

```
 Sub Duct1Desc()
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Duct1").OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=AB1"
 With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Duct1")
 .Font.ColorIndex = 3
 .Font.Size = 16
 .Font.Bold = True
 End With
 End Sub
```

But in this issue I have got an error, that VBA doesn't support this property or method.

Can anyone help me to bind these 2 codes together?

Thanks[image]

Comment: I don't understand, you have working code to change the text colour in the first block.

Comment: @SJR yes indeed

Comment: Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am getting black and small font when I run the code with formula. I want to keep the original fond size and colour (red, 16). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Dim s As Shape

Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("myBox")
s.DrawingObject.Formula = "=B2"
```

OK I thought the problem was the linking, not the formatting: this works for me.

```
Sub Duct1Desc()
    Dim s
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Duct1")
    s.OLEFormat.Object.Formula = "=A1"
    With s.DrawingObject
        .Font.ColorIndex = 3
        .Font.Size = 20
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For me doesn't. I see no reaction regrettably.